# NoSQL / Redis Scaling Theory

Tags: networking, nosql, scalability, redis, multiprocessing

Is it more efficient for a key-value data store such as Redis to handle X number of requests over 1 client connection or 1 request per client over X number of client connections?

Answer (score 1):

In theory reusing a connection means that less work is required on the connection overhead so it is technically more efficient. However, in practice latency means that using a single connection is dramatically slower with the server being idle most of the time.

Redis performance is almost never limited by the CPU - it can quite easily serve 100 requests on separate connections in the time it would otherwise spend waiting for the second request on a single connection.